# Can netplan bring down the routing for an interface entirely if another interface has a priority route-metric?

Tags: 20.04, netplan, routing

I figured certain quirks with networking in several libraries that I do not want to deal with fixing individually are gone if the interface that is not the priority route-metric is taken out of the picture entirely (possibly because their connections are not persistent anymore and lets them re-connect to the new higher priority interface (but that's besides the question)).

I wonder if netplan can be set up to just discard that previous lower priority routing entirely (or even bring down that interface temporarily I guess) until the interface with the higher priority gets out of the way.

To say it in a practical example: "normal operation: eth0 only -> wlan0 is temporarily up: eth0 is not even routed now -> when wlan0 is down: back to eth0"

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, there is no way to do this through netplan.  Metrics are supported using their standard meaning.